# How to align search icon and autocomplete component on same line

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using **autocomplete** component in my project and i have added **search** icon as suffix to the component as shown in below image
[image]

I am trying to align **icon** and **autocomplete** component's input field on the same line like this.

[image]

I am unable to do this.Here is the forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ao75y?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css:

```
mat-icon{
      position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}
```

See here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ao75y-wtqj1n?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.css

Comment: I got it, Thank you.

Comment: happy to help:)

Comment: please open a new question... and let me know when you post new one

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160180/how-to-set-max-height-for-the-scroll-bar-in-autocomplete-component`  Please answer to this question.