# How to set max-height for the scroll bar in autocomplete component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **autocomplete** component in my project, along with the autocomplete component i have added an **button** inside the component for adding a new customer as shown in below image.
[image]

Here i want to achieve 2 things:

1) I want to make button as fixed even after the scroll(i,e Add New Customer).

2) I want to reduce the height of the scroll bar.
How can i do this? Here is the forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ao75y-cwhqay?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `position:sticky`:

```
.add-button{
  position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

2) Use `height` to `.cdk-overlay-pane` with `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane{
    height: 150px!important;}
```

See here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ao75y-fc23aj?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.css

Comment: You saved my day,Thanks a lot.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Still one more help, Please answer to this question.`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162800/display-the-value-of-a-selected-option-outside-the-input-field-in-chips-autocomp/52162952#52162952`