# Display the value of a selected option outside the input field in Chips Autocomplete component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

**Scenario :**

- I am using **Chips Autocomplete** component.
- On selecting the particular option from the list it is displaying the
  selected option as the **chip** in the input filed as shown in below
  image.

  [image]

**Todo :**

- I want these chips to be displayed outside the input field, 
  means in any other div.Like below image 
  How can i do this ? 

  [image]

  Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-sezbmm?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `<mat-chip>` out of `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>`

```
 <div>
      <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>

  </div>
```

See here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-ao3bzb?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html

Comment: In the same example i need search filter to search players name,means even if i type second name it should appear.like in mobile contact list.

Comment: for more answers(other users see and maybe they can help) I reccomand you to post another question

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `input` field outside (top or bottom) of the `</mat-chip-list>` and you should be fine.

You might want to add some padding/margin after that :)

Comment: Sorry for my wrong assumption, here there is input type it's an autocomplete component.I want chips to be displayed in other div, only the chips.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
as you are already using fruits array to add or remove the items,
 thus you can access fruits array any where in your html file of that component

<h1> *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">{{fruit}} </h1>

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `auto-complete` to search players and display the selected players as `chip-list` inside the outer `div` as like below

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">    
    <input matInput placeholder="New fruit..." #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
            {{fruit}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>    
</mat-form-field>

<div class="otherDiv">
    <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
            {{fruit}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

Comment: search i happening fine  for the  first name, How can i call the by typing second name too.

Comment: refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete?embed=1&file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html